# R.id.history cannot be resolved

Tags: android

i have written a program for list view.the name of the list view is history.but in java code  ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.history); there is an error showing that R.id.history cannot be resolved.i coul not solve the issue.can anyone help me?

Comment: It is possible that your resource file is not being regenerated correctly but before we go down that route.. can you post your layout xml and also does the exception happen at runtime or design time?

Comment: please clean your project once  .